# Apache Syncope - Installation with Tomcat8.5.24

Tags: tomcat, installation, tar, apache-syncope

Apache Syncope - apache-syncope-2.0.7.deb installation requires tomcat8 dependency.

tomcat version 8.5.24 is installed using the tar.gz.

Running sudo dpkg -i apache-syncope-2.0.7.deb there is an error

Preparing to unpack apache-syncope-2.0.7.deb ...
Unpacking apache-syncope (2.0.7) over (2.0.7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache-syncope:
 apache-syncope depends on tomcat8; however:
  Package tomcat8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package apache-syncope (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache-syncope

This is because tomcat was not installed using apt-get or .deb.

How to state that tomcat8 is installed or let the dpkg know that tomcat8 is installed. how does dpkg checks for tomcat8 is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

For Syncope GUI you need to add tomcat path:

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat{X}
```

And don’t forget to configure a manager user; if not done yet, ensure that the content of **$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml** looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="manager" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

More details is available in [Syncope documentation](https://syncope.apache.org/docs/getting-started.html#gui-installer).